# Don't understand "TensorFlow Object Detection" with OpenCV GitHub Wiki

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection, mobilenet

I am trying to use [this wiki](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API) to detect objects with Python OpenCV. But I don't understand this line of code we're supposed to use:

```
python tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py --input /path/to/model.pb --config /path/to/example.config --output /path/to/graph.pbtxt
```

I want to use MobileNet-SSD v3, so I downloaded [this](https://gist.github.com/dkurt/54a8e8b51beb3bd3f770b79e56927bd7), as well as the [tf_text_graph_ssd.py file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py) and the [ssdlite_mobilenet_v3_large_320x320_coco.config file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssdlite_mobilenet_v3_large_320x320_coco.config).

But none of the files have the *.pb extension listed in the python command line, and [this file](https://gist.github.com/dkurt/54a8e8b51beb3bd3f770b79e56927bd7) already has the *.pbtxt output-extension, so I don't get what that line has to do exactly?

This probably is a very basic question, but I've been struggling with this for some time now so I thought I may ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [wiki](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API) asking you to download the **.pb file** which is a model from the **Model Zoo**. However the link is broken. Here is the [the working link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md).

[MobileNet-SSD v3](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.tar.gz) is here, you can find other MobileNet_SSD v3 models in the link above as well.

After unzip the downloaded file, you will find the file, **frozen_inference_graph.pb**. That is the model file you need.